# How to connect Conv3D output to MaxPooling2D in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I'm using Keras to implement CNN.  People often use Conv2D to do classification tasks.  However, I want to get relationships between two images, then I decide to try Conv3D.  However, I couldn't manage the dimension output from Conv3D and match the following layers.

More specifically, I want to apply (5,5,2) filter on two stacked images which are (480, 640, 2), and output(480, 640, 1) tensor.

[image]

Original Conv2D code: (work fine)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',input_shape=(480, 640, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
...
```

Conv3D code: (Don't know how to concatenate Conv3D and MaxPooling2D)

```
model.add(Conv3D(32, 2, input_shape=(480, 640, 2, 1), data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
...
```

Comment: Your Conv2D model already applies a (5,5,2) filter if you say `kernel_size=5`. There is no advantage in changing it to 3D with `kernel_size=(5,5,2)`, that would pass a `(5,5,2,1)` filter (exactly the same number of parameters) without any movement in the third dimension. (And if you use `padding ='same'` in this layer, you will add undesired border effects, like ghost images for padding).

Comment: @DanielMöller I think I had some misunderstanding with 2D convolution on a multichannel image.  After checking your explanation and [this document](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/), I know how to fix the problem now.  Tks :)

Answer (score 1):

Stack both the images (remember to stack acc. to the backend you are using, theano is `channels_first` and tensorflow is `channels_last`) and pass 2 as the number of channels in `Conv2D`.

Or if you have many channels for each images, then again stack them up and pass the total number of channels to `Conv2D`.